# Элементы с position:relative перекрывают элементы с css свойством transform: scale

Tags: html, css, transform

При ховере добавляю на строку таблички css свойство transform:scaleX(n) при попытке открыть выпадающее меню свитчеры перекрывают его

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: ес, офкорс -______